# How to get access to Spotlight search field in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode11, xcuitest

Using Xcode 11 with iPhone 11 Simulator. 
Trying to input some text in Spotlight search:

```
let springboard = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
springboard.swipeDown()

let spotlightSearchField = springboard.searchFields["SpotlightSearchField"]
spotlightSearchField.typeText("Some text")
```

Can't find an element with accessibility identifier `SpotlightSearchField`, although the Spotlight search panel is visible. It is also absent in elements tree, if I call `debugDescription`. 
DebugDescription output doesn't contain any element of dropdown panel with spotlight and siri suggestions - only main screen elements.

But AccessibilityInspector can find Spotlight search field and shows its Identifier.

[image: AccessibilityInspector]

So ho can I get access to this field in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SpotlightSearchField` is a part of the **Spotlight**, not SpringBoard.

you should interact with it like this:

```swift
let spotlight = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Spotlight")
let spotlightSearchField = spotlight.textFields["SpotlightSearchField"]
spotlightSearchField.typeText("Some text")
```

Good luck!